# Strange results using tramp :session in org-mode

Tags: emacs, putty, org-mode, plink, tramp

TLTR;  If you use Emacs Org-Mode Tramp on Windows with Plink with SSH sesion. It creates strange outputs

Long Text:
I use Emacs Org-Mode. Which is a great tool. And i liked to use in a literate DevOps way. Which is also a great Idea, document your work while you are on it.

You will hate me, i have to use a Windows station @work. So i tested it with Putty plink:

```
#+NAME: harddisk_worker001.sh
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /plink:worker001:/tmp 
df --human-readable --local --exclude-type=tmpfs --exclude-type=overlay | awk '{print $5 "\t" $1}' | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort --reverse)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: harddisk_worker001.sh
| Use% | Filesystem                |
|  73% | /dev/mapper/system-lvroot |
|   6% | /dev/mapper/system-lvopt  |
|   6% | /dev/mapper/system-lvhome |
|  47% | /dev/sda1                 |
|   2% | /dev/mapper/system-lvtmp  |
|  27% | /dev/mapper/system-lvvar  |
|   0% | devtmpfs                  |
```

The Result was great, but i liked to also the *:session* feature of it, to speed it up:

```
#+NAME: harddisk_worker001.sh
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /plink:worker001:/tmp :session worker001
df --human-readable --local --exclude-type=tmpfs --exclude-type=overlay | awk '{print $5 "\t" $1}' | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort --reverse)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: harddisk_worker001.sh
| Filesystem                |
| /dev/mapper/system-lvroot |
| /dev/mapper/system-lvopt  |
| /dev/mapper/system-lvhome |
| /dev/sda1                 |
| /dev/mapper/system-lvtmp  |
| /dev/mapper/system-lvvar  |
| devtmpfs                  |
```

Which was not the exspected result! Can you explain why the table differs? I am not able see the root cause of this. Except a bug in the tramp-plink implementation, but i am not sure about that.

Can you replay this?

Comment: I would like to help, but I'm not able to explain the behavior of Trump.  -- Michael Albinus, maintainer of Tramp.

Comment:  I can understand this. I correct the spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know too much about org, so I have debugged the resulting Tramp calls. Your first command results in `org-babel--shell-command-on-region`, which invokes a proper `process-file` call.

Your second example, with the `:session` argument, doesn't seem to call any Tramp operation related to processes. So I believe org is trying something internally, which I cannot debug further. Maybe a process invocation which isn't Tramp aware, who knows.

I recommend to write an org fault report.